# Can't create mongodb db

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

According to this [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm) using `use mays` should create a db if it isn't already created:

> MongoDB use DATABASE_NAME is used to create database. The command will
>   create a new database, if it doesn't exist otherwise it will return
>   the existing database.

So why doesn't `mongo use mays` work?

```
root@server88-208-249-95:~# mongo use mays
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: use
2015-09-16T22:17:20.316+0100 file [mays] doesn't exist
failed to load: mays
```

Comment: Default directory for mongodb to store collections is `/data/db` do you have that folder ?

Comment: you need to be in the mongo shell `$ mongo` and then `> use mays` within it

Comment: Add that as the answer  please :) `/var/lib/mongodb` this is my db path

Comment: @aug2uag I meant you add it as the answer please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'use' command doesn't work with mongo command.
You have to open mongo shell and then use the 'use' command.

Open terminal -> enter 'mongo' to get mongo shell ->
use db_name

This will create a DB if it doesn't exists already.

A DB doesn't show up when using 'show dbs' until you create a collection in it.

Use db.createCollection("collection_name") and then use 'show dbs' and you will see your newly created DB.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create at least one collection before it saves the database.  Issuing a use will create it, but will not automatically save it.  You can create an empty collection with db.createCollection("test").  To verify try the following commands from the mongo shell:

```
use mays
show dbs   (mays will not show up)
db.createCollection("test")
show dbs   (mays will show up)
```

Comment: Thanks, although totally illogical not to show up when you just created it.